# Issue with adding a custom dynamic colour to WYSIWIG

Tags: php, wordpress, function, advanced-custom-fields

I'm attempting to add a variable to a colour palette, with the code below. The top 2 colours work, but my third colour is not being added, as you can see on my code; the echo's will display the correct colour from the CMS, but the moment it gets into the function, this variable does not work.

```
// Get current user identification
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$current_role = $current_user->roles[0];


// Loop through ACF repeater in the options
if( have_rows('group_colour', 'options') ):
    while ( have_rows('group_colour','options') ) : the_row();

        // Set the selected user role and the colour
        $colourrole = get_sub_field('user_role');
        $colourvalue = get_sub_field('role_colour');

            // If options user role matches the logged in user, get the colour and remove the #
            if ($current_role == $colourrole){
                $colour_no_hash = str_replace('#', '', $colourvalue);
                echo $colour_no_hash;



                // Customize the TinyMCE Color Palette. Attempting to add a colour for 'Custom Login'. Other 2 colours work.
                function wptb_tinymce_options($options) {

                    $custom_colours =  '"000000", "Black",
                                        "00AC9F", "Custom Teal",
                                        "' . $colour_no_hash . '", "Custom Login"';
                    $options['textcolor_map'] = '['.$custom_colours.']';
                    return $options;
                }
                add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'wptb_tinymce_options');

            }

    endwhile;
else :
endif;
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I'm curious as to why `$custom_colours` is not an assoc and it is a CSV string? Would it not be easier as an assoc?

Comment: Sorry, i'm not sure on what you mean with assoc?

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified originally but I was feeling lazy. I meant an associative array e.g. `$custom_colours = [ '000000' => 'Black', [...] ]`

Comment: @Script47 I'll look at this, I found this example of changing the WYSIWIG colours online and hoped i'd be to integrate my code into it. Will this be far off?

Comment: Would not be easier to use something like [TinyMCE](https://www.tiny.cloud/) with the [color picker plguin](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/colorpicker/)?

Comment: @Script47 This only needs to show one option of a highlighting colour depending who is logged in. I feel what I have is quite close. I tried an assoc but this didn't make any difference unfortunately.

Comment: So, I think this has something to do with the loading of the page. I feel the variable hasn't been set before the function has been initialised. Maybe to do with the add_filter? If I just echo the variable anywhere inside the function it is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I believe your issue is with variable scopes.

You're declaring `$colour_no_hash` outside of the function, and the function isn't able to access it. You can inherit the variable in the function with a `use`:

```
$colour_no_hash = str_replace('#', '', $colourvalue);
echo $colour_no_hash;

// Customize the TinyMCE Color Palette. Attempting to add a colour for 'Custom Login'. Other 2 colours work.
wptb_tinymce_options = function ($options) use ($colour_no_hash) {

    $custom_colours =  '"000000", "Black",
                        "00AC9F", "Custom Teal",
                        "' . $colour_no_hash . '", "Custom Login"';
    $options['textcolor_map'] = '['.$custom_colours.']';
    return $options;
};
```

**EDIT** Changed the above to an anonymous function

Source: [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

Comment: Thank you for this. The 'use' function seems to cause a syntax error of incorrect use of 'use' (this that makes sense).

Comment: Ahh, my bad, this only works on anonymous functions - I'll edit the code, see if that works for you? not sure if you'll be able to pass it that way?